# Limit of weighed partial sums

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f_n(k)>0$ be a non-negative function, defined on $k\in\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$, such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(k)=f(k)$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f(k)=0$.

Also, let $w_n(k)$ be a weight function such that $\sum_{k=1}^n w_n(k)=1$,

I'd like to argue that, if
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}w_n(k)=0,$$
then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nw_n(k)f_n(k)=0.$$
An example of this type of $w_n(k)$ is a binomial density with probability $p$: $w_n(k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.

Also, I'd like to argue that, if
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}w_n(k)=w(k)~~~{\rm and}~~~\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}w(k)=0,$$
then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nw_n(k)f_n(k)\ne0.$$
And I want to find conditions that satisfy that $\sum_{k=1}^nw_n(k)f_n(k)$ converges to a non-zero constant, i.e.,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nw_n(k)f_n(k)=c>0.$$
An example of this type of $w_n(k)$ is a binomial density with probability $a/n$ with a constant $a\in(0,n)$: $w_n(k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}(a/n)^k(1-a/n)^{n-k}$.

Can anybody help me prove these?

Comment: The first part, as stated, is not true. Consider, for instance, $f_n:\{0,...,n\}\to [0,+\infty)$ given by 
$$
f_n(k)=
\begin{cases}
1 & k=n\\
0 & k\neq n
\end{cases}
$$
and $w_n=f_n$. This verifies the assumptions, as $f_n(k)\to f(k)=0$ for all $k$, and $w_n$ are weight functions for all $n$. Yet for all $n$,  
$$
\sum_{k=0}^nw_n(k)f_n(k)=1
$$
We need stronger assumptions, like for instance uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$. Or, that there is a sequence $s_k$ s.t. $\sum_k s_k<+\infty$ and s.t. for all $n, k$, $w_n(k)f_n(k)<s_k$

Comment: The second isn't true, either. Consider 
$$
f_n(k)=
\begin{cases}
1 & k=0\\
0 & k\neq 0
\end{cases}
$$
and 
$$
w_n(k)=
\begin{cases}
1 & k=1\\
0 & k\neq 1
\end{cases}
$$
which verify your assumptions. However, for all $n$, 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n w_n(k)f_n(k)=0
$$